# Redis and socket to send to only some client

Tags: python, node.js, redis, socket.io

I have a server like this in `node.js`:

```
socket.on('connection', function(client) {
        const subscribe = redis.createClient(6379, '127.0.0.1')

        subscribe.psubscribe('kitchen_*');

        subscribe.on("pmessage", function(pattern, channel, message) {
            client.emit(channel, message);
            log('msg', "received from channel #" + channel + " : " + message);
        });
});
```

In client I have like this:

```
socket.on('kitchen_companyName', function (data) {
        console.log('received a message: ', data);
      });
```

Now I want to receive the message only for `kitchen_companyName` in the client but even if the company name is `kitchen_hello` I am receiving the message. I am publishing to redis from python using `pyredis`.

```
r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379)
r.publish('kitchen_'+request.user.user_company, message)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding a condition to check the channel and emit only to that channel,

```
subscribe.on("pmessage", function(pattern, channel, message) {
    if(channel == "kitchen_companyName") {
      client.emit(channel, message);
      log('msg', "received from channel #" + channel + " : " + message);
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem I don't have the actual channel name on the server. I have the actual channel name `prefix after _` on client only.

Comment: I managed to send `companyName` via redis and it's working fine now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your subscription is to all channels, having `"kitchen_"` as prefix, watch that `*` in your subscription command.

So any message being published to any channel starting by `"kitchen_"` will come to your subscriber.

Change your subscription message to `"kitchen_companyName"` and you will receive only messages for that channel.

Note, that you can subscribe one client to multiple channels.